# Resolving issue with Materialize dropdown

Tags: html, css

**For reference:**

1. The tool I'm using: https://materializecss.com/
2. The outcome I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRZHk.jpg
3. The outcome I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Itv.jpg

I have a dropdown on the navbar of my webpage. Before adding the class

```
.sidenav-trigger
```

To the following :

```
<li><a href="" data-target="slide-out-settings" class="sidenav-trigger" style="color: black;"><i class="material-icons">settings</i>Settings</a></li>
```

Which is sat inside of the following `<ul>`:

```html
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'FullSearch:Search' %}" style="color: black;"><i class="material-icons">search</i>Search</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'UserProfiles:UserProfile' Username=UserName %}" style="color: black;"><i class="material-icons">person</i>Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'Discover:DiscoverPage' %}" style="color: black;"><i class="material-icons">public</i>Explore</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="" data-target="slide-out-settings" class="sidenav-trigger" style="color: black;"><i class="material-icons">settings</i>Settings</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'UserLogout:LogoutPage' %}" style="color: black;"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>Logout</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The dropdown looks as intended.

Simply removing this class won't work as I need it in order to have a pullout sidebar.

**How can I resolve the alignment of the text in the dropdown?**

Comment: Please include the CSS affecting the HTML you've provided in the snippet so that others can reproduce the problem. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: For this HTML page, the only CSS is the inline CSS that is already in the question and the materialize CSS. Should I add what is required to link in the header in order to get the HTML working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the height to **auto !important** as following:

```
<li>
  <a href="" data-target="slide-out-settings" class="sidenav-trigger" style="color: black; height: auto !important;">
    <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
      Settings
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Adding `!important` is rarely the best approach. Using inline styles is also not very maintainable.

Comment: I agree, but i only see this solution if he realy want to use the `.sidenav-trigger` class

Comment: This response has now worked! Do you know of an alternative method that does not require the use of the `.sidenav-trigger` class

Comment: @Wavegunner232 unfortunately no, you'll have to ask a new question.

Comment: Alright, well, this answer worked and so I'm going to give it the checkmark.
Huge thank you for spending the time to respond to this.